# Efficient way to achieve inheritance

Tags: javascript

What will be the best way to get rid of repetitive code

```
let BaseErrorResponse = function(mes, rti, rsi, st) {
    return {
        "message": msg,
        "response_type_id": rti,
        "response_status_id": rsi,
        "status": st
    }
};


let InvalidParamResponse = function(mes, rti, rsi, st, ip) {
    return {
        "message": msg,
        "response_type_id": rti,
        "response_status_id": rsi,
        "status": st,
        "invalid_params": ip
    }
};


let SuccessResponse = function(msg, rti, rsi, st, data) {
    return {
        "message": null,
        "response_type_id": null,
        "response_status_id": null,
        "status": null,
        "data": {}
    }
};
```

Comment: In `SuccessResponse`, didn't you mean `"data": data` rather than `"data": {}`? Also, why the `null`s?

Comment: Ohhh...I missed it!    it just a work in progress. I am still completing.....

Comment: MDN [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you're using ES2015 (aka ES6), seems like `class` might be an efficient option for you:

```
class BaseErrorResponse {
    constructor(mes, rti, rsi, st) {
        this.message = msg;
        this.response_type_id = rti;
        this.response_status_id = rsi;
        this.status = st;
    }
}

class InvalidParamResponse extends BaseErrorResponse {
    constructor(mes, rti, rsi, st, ip) {
        super(mes, rti, rsi, st);
        this.invalid_params = ip;
    }
}

class SuccessResponse extends BaseErrorResponse {
    constructor(msg, rti, rsi, st, data) {
        super(null, null, null, null); // Why the nulls when you're passing
                                       // those args in?
        this.data = {};                // Didn't you mean = data here?
    }
}
```

Based on your reply to my comment on the question, that last one would be:

```
class SuccessResponse extends BaseErrorResponse {
    constructor(msg, rti, rsi, st, data) {
        super(msg, rti, rsi, st);
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just [merge objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
let BaseErrorResponse = function(mes, rti, rsi, st) {
    return {
        "message": msg,
        "response_type_id": rti,
        "response_status_id": rsi,
        "status": st
    }
};


let InvalidParamResponse = function(mes, rti, rsi, st, ip) {
    return Object.assign(BaseErrorResponse(mes, rti, rsi, st), {
        "invalid_params": ip
    });
};


let SuccessResponse = function(mes, rti, rsi, st, data) {
    return Object.assign(BaseErrorResponse(mes, rti, rsi, st), {
        "data": {}
    });
};
```

It might be a good idea to make these into actual constructors that inherit from each other, though.

```
function BaseErrorResponse(mes, rti, rsi, st) {
    this.message = msg;
    this.response_type_id = rti;
    this.response_status_id = rsi;
    this.status = st;
}

function InvalidParamResponse(mes, rti, rsi, st, ip) {
    BaseErrorResponse.call(this, mes, rti, rsi, st);
    this.invalid_params = ip;
}

InvalidParamResponse.prototype = Object.create(BaseErrorResponse.prototype);
InvalidParamResponse.prototype.constructor = InvalidParamResponse;

function SuccessResponse(mes, rti, rsi, st, data) {
    BaseErrorResponse.call(this, mes, rti, rsi, st);
    this.data = data;
}

SuccessResponse.prototype = Object.create(BaseErrorResponse.prototype);
SuccessResponse.prototype.constructor = SuccessResponse;
```

Comment: Re the second part of your answer: Since the OP is using ES2015 (based on `let`), it's much simpler just to use the `class` sugar rather than doing the plumbing oneself. (Re first part: Absolutely a good way to do it if ending up with plain objects, as the OP's code currently does, is desired/useful.)

Answer (score 0):

A little easier solution as for me is:

```
var BaseErrorResponse = function(mes, rti, rsi, st) {
  return { mes, rti, rsi, st };
};

var InvalidParamResponse = function(mes, rti, rsi, st, ip) {
  var response = BaseErrorResponse(mes, rti, rsi, st);
  response.invalid_params = ip;
  return response;
};

var SuccessResponse = function() {
  var response = BaseErrorResponse(null, null, null, null);
  response.data = {};
  return response;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used **T.J. Crowder** code as below and its working fine for me

```
'use strict';
class BaseErrorResponse {
    constructor(msg, rti, rsi, st) {
        this.message = msg;
        this.response_type_id = rti;
        this.response_status_id = rsi;
        this.status = st;
    }
}

class InvalidParamResponse extends BaseErrorResponse {
    constructor(mes, rti, rsi, st, ip) {
        super(mes, rti, rsi, st);
        this.invalid_params = ip;
    }
}

class SuccessResponse extends BaseErrorResponse {
    constructor(msg, rti, rsi, st, data) {
        super(msg, rti, rsi, st); // Why the nulls when you're passing
                                       // those args in?
        this.data = data;                // Didn't you mean = data here?
    }
}


(()=> {
    let sr = new SuccessResponse('Message', 1, 2, 3, {name: 'vivek'});
    console.log(sr);
})();
```

**OUTPUT:**

test )

```
node js-class-test.js 
SuccessResponse {
  message: 'Message',
  response_type_id: 1,
  response_status_id: 2,
  status: 3,
  data: { name: 'vivek' } }
```